# apache with ssl in openstack vm

Tags: apache, ssl, virtual-machine, openstack

I have openstack Mitaka installation with flat network with 1 controller node and 1 compute node. I have a Red Hat VM with Apache/2.0.63 and openssl OpenSSL 1.0.1h. 
When I open web pages hosted on this VM, there is random behavior on web page. It is loaded successfully sometime or sometimes it fails loading page displaying the following message.

**Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
 Request header field is missing ':' separator.**

But when I switch to http, web pages are displayed as expected. Also, with same Apache and SSL configuration, everything runs as expected on physical machine.

Thanks!

Comment: you should try at least `ocata` since `mitaka` has been deprecated for a while. And what's your question?

Comment: We have mitaka setup only. Problem is highlighted in the post itself!

Comment: Can you check horizon logs ?? Sometimes you will get Too Many open files issue..

Comment: there is no such error.my problem is apache launched on vm.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by upgrading apache version from httpd-2.0.63 to httpd-2.2.34.